# Dynamically create new objects in java

Tags: java, loops, object, for-loop, iteration

I want to dynamically create objects of a class using an array.
This is what i have so far:

```
int[] n = new int[10];

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  MyClass n[i] = new MyClass();
  n[i].setNumber(i);
  n[i].printNumber();
}
```

The class MyClass conatins the constructor for MyClass and methods for set and print.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Eran How do i dynamically create objects of a class using an array?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "dynamically"?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Not statc, i.e: MyClass 1 = new MyClass();

Comment: Your MyClass object is created dynamically, because it's created inside for loop, which is executed at runtime only...what else dynamicity you wish to add..?

Comment: Sorry, your "not static" example is not clear (and does not compile). Can you point us to the definition of "dynamic" and "static" that you are using in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code.

The array should be of `MyClass` type, not int :

```
MyClass[] n = new MyClass [10];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  n[i] = new MyClass();
  n[i].setNumber(i);
  n[i].printNumber();
}
```

And your loop should start at 0.